# Call view from Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, procedure

I have a user VIEW, let's call it `[MIKE].Table` wich does a filtered select
`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TL_FILTERKEY in (1,2,3)`

So, if Mike connects to the server and executes

```
"SELECT * FROM TABLE"
```

he will see only part of the data from table.

There is also a procedure with dbo rights and permision to Mike for execution as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE tbSelect
as
SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

If Mike executes `exec tbSelect` he will see ALL rows from Table, but not filtered.

How to write the procedure so that it will select data from the user view(filtered rows)?

I tried recreate the procedure 'WITH EXECUTE AS 'Mike'' and 'WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER', however all rows are returned.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little confusing, and you don't mention your SQL Server version, but I suspect that your problem is due to [schemas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190387.aspx). When you reference an object without a schema, SQL Server looks for an object in the user's default schema first, then the dbo schema.

As a complete guess, I think you have a user called Mike whose default schema is also `Mike`, a view called `Mike.Table` and a table called `dbo.Table`. When Mike runs his query `Table` is resolved to `Mike.Table` but when a db_owner queries `Table` it's resolved as `dbo.Table`.

To avoid confusion, you should probably use clearer object names (at least for testing) and [always qualify object name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283095.aspx)s with the owner:

```
create table dbo.TestTable (col1 int)
go

insert into dbo.TestTable 
select 1
union all
select 2
union all
select 3
go

-- this will return all rows
select col1 from dbo.TestTable
go

create view dbo.TestView
as
select col1
from dbo.TestTable
where col1 >= 2
go

-- this will return 2 rows
select col1 from dbo.TestView
go

create procedure dbo.TestProc
as
select col1 from dbo.TestView
go

-- this will also return 2 rows
exec dbo.TestProc
go

drop proc dbo.TestProc
go
drop View dbo.TestView
go
drop table dbo.TestTable
go
```

Comment: Yes, we can get data from view as [schemas].ViewName within procedure.
The idea was to get a trick with selecting data without schemas. May be it is possible by doing it through system tables.

The problem solved by creatting mapping table: [user] -> [view].